# SVG responsive on div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, svg, responsive

As the title said, I want to add an SVG border animation to a div. I tryed with a static div but now I want to make it works even if the div width and height change dynamically (as thumbnail class with Bootstrap)

Here is my SVG :

```
<svg>
    <line class="top" x1="0" y1="0" x2="3000" y2="0"/>
    <line class="left" x1="0" y1="3000" x2="0" y2="0"/>
    <line class="bottom" x1="3000" y1="300" x2="0" y2="300"/>
    <line class="right" x1="300" y1="0" x2="300" y2="300"/>
</svg>
```

Thanks for the help, here is a jsbin : http://jsbin.com/suvinakaqa/1/edit

Comment: Do you need left line animate till end of the div and top line till right of the div?

Comment: For now the animation is not really the problem, I want the 4 lines to fit perfectly to the div, even if the div have a percentage width/height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the SVG to responsively fill the `<div>`, you need to give it a `viewBox` and set `preserveAspectRatio="none"` so that it stretches to fill the `<div>` both horizontally and vertically.  Otherwise it will just keep its aspect ratio and just scale up or down to fit inside the `<div>`.

Note that the stretching that occurs, now that you've disabled aspect ratio, will cause the horizontal lines to appear to have a different width to the vertical ones.  To fix that you could add `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"` to the lines.

```css
.myDiv
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none"
       stroke="black" stroke-width="4">
    <line class="top" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
    <line class="left" x1="0" y1="100" x2="0" y2="0" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
    <line class="bottom" x1="100" y1="100" x2="0" y2="100" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
    <line class="right" x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: But I had another weird problem. I have a thumbnail class, when you hover it a text in a div appear. I want to do also in it a svg border animation. But the SVG line won't animate and I don't know why
here is a jsbin showing perfectly my problem : http://jsbin.com/gezativuca/1/edit
thanks in advance

Comment: That's really should be a different question.  But the reason is because you use a selector with "`.thumb:hover > .svg-text` ...". However `.svg-text` is not a direct child of `.thumb`. It is a grandchild.

Answer (score -1):

For eg you have following in HTML

```
<div class="myClass">
    <svg>
       <line class="top" x1="0" y1="0" x2="3000" y2="0"/>
       <line class="left" x1="0" y1="3000" x2="0" y2="0"/>
       <line class="bottom" x1="3000" y1="300" x2="0" y2="300"/>
       <line class="right" x1="300" y1="0" x2="300" y2="300"/>
   </svg>
</div>
```

Please use following CSS

```
.myClass svg{
  width:100% !important;
  height:auto;
}
```

Comment: You will need to use Media queries and Javascript/jQuery to handle width and height of lines..